# How to run DevNullSmtp.jar in background by specifying path to store message and port number?

Tags: jar, background

I need to run the simple SMTP server for sample email communication. I can run the jar and do the configuration from UI, but its tedious to do it everytime. Is there a way to store all the config or run the server in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows

```
java -jar C:\Installed\DevNullSmtp.jar -p 25 -console -s C:\Installed\mailbox -d abc.com,pqr.com
```

for Linux

```
nohup java -jar DevNullSmtp.jar -p 2525 -console -s /home/email -d abc.com,pqr.com &
```

`abc.com,pqr.com` are the domains from which emails should be received.